# Allowed memory size of error X on nusoap

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

PHP is connected to SOAP between NuSOAP and I can recieve data from PHP. After getting data, I get timeout error because of data size is huge which is received. You can see xdebug print out on below.I can run same service using PHP native SOAP command.

http://s15.postimg.org/c9491lf1n/2015_03_08_02_07_10.jpg

I am using following settings. I can not get a solution about the above error although I increased maximum limit as possible as much.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', "512M");
ini_set('max_execution_time', 60000); //x saniye
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("max_input_time ", 6000);
```

I am waiting your solution about this issue urgently. Thank for your support.

Edit:
My NuSOAP client function:

```
function nusoapCall($method,$params,$returnType="array"){
    global $WSDLURL,$debugMode;
    require_once('tools/nusoap/nusoap.php');    
    $soapClient = new nusoap_client($WSDLURL, 'wsdl');
    $soapClient->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
    $soapClient->decode_utf8 = false;
    $soapClient->setUseCURL(true);
    //$soapClient->loadWSDL();
    $soapClient->setCurlOption(CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    if($debugMode == 1){
        $soapClient->debug_flag = false;
    }

    $tResult = $soapClient->call( $method,$params);
    if($returnType=="object"){
        $tResult = array_to_object($tResult);
    }

    $soapError = $soapClient->getError();
    echo $soapClient->getDebug();
    if (!empty($soapError)) {

        $errorMessage = 'Nusoap object creation failed: ' . $soapError;
        throw new Exception($errorMessage);
        return false;
    }else{
        return $tResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: either allocate more memory, or use less.

Comment: @Dagon I don't think it causes about decrease or increase. If I set the memory to 2048M, I get again the same error.

Comment: reduce memory useage - already answered

Comment: @Dagon thank you for your reply. Although I set the memory usage to 16m, the result did not change. Error: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12323197 bytes)